# Do timers on Android have tolerance?

Tags: android, timer

On iOS, most, if not all of the mechanisms for scheduling delayed work allow you to specify a "tolerance".

Examples:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/3329231-schedule

If you are not familiar with the concept, tolerance allows the operating system to deliberately fire a timer later than the scheduled target time. This lets the operating system move nearby timers around to cluster them together, so the CPU can spend more time sleeping, and conserve power.
Many timers on iOS actually have a default tolerance of 10%, so if you schedule a callback after 30 seconds, it will often fire at 33 seconds instead!

Windows has this too, Microsoft have [quite a good doc about it](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F9%2Fc%2F5%2F9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a%2Ftimercoal.docx&wdOrigin=BROWSELINK):

I've looked and googled for an equivalent on Android - but as far as I can tell there isn't any such thing? None of the timer related methods on the Google developer docs site seem to mention tolerance, leeway, or any other similar term.

Am I missing something? Are there timers with tolerance on Android, or does this simply not exist?

Comment: Not sure if [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) and [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) fits your criteria.

Comment: Those are cool, but it looks like they are much bigger hammers (e.g. Doze puts the whole phone to sleep), and not the same kind of thing

Comment: You may want to mention on what scale of time you want/use case. Possibly related: [ScheduleThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) with [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Comment: What kind of timer are you using?  Alarm?  TimerTask?  Handler?  Hard to answer without knowing that.  In general, timers in android are short and don't need/want tolerance (timer task, handler), or are long and have it built into the system but are not configurable (alarm, work manager, job scheduler).  Android has more of a "trust the system" type mentality.

Comment: On short (interactive) timeframes, such as 100ms up to perhaps 2 minutes. As you say, longer timers are likely to exceed the time that the user has the app open, so need to use a dedicated background role such as jobs or notifications